# Proper usage of pthread_detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to get a function to start up another thread, and then return, with the thread still running.  It seems like pthread_detach() would take care of the memory and whatnot for me, although I'm not entirely sure.  This is the code for the function:

```
void function() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&state.continueLoopingMutex);
    if(state.continueLooping == true) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&state.continueLoopingMutex);
        return;
    }
    state.continueLooping = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&state.continueLoopingMutex);
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runLoop, NULL);
    pthread_detach(thread);
}
```

(The loop will stop when continueLooping is set to false, once the loop finishes it just returns without doing anything else).

Is there anything wrong with this structure that would cause a memory leak, etc., that I should care about?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong.
Yes the `pthread_detach` will take care to release the resources of the thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the threads continue to run simultaneously, it won't make a difference whether you detach the thread or not. But it will be harder or less idiomatic to collect resource (like a return value) from a detached thread. And yes, this piece of code does not expose any memory leaks.